# How to animate an ImageView from left to right and right to left

Tags: android, button, jquery-animate, imageview, clicklistener

I'm trying to develop a game in which when the user taps the right button, the ImageView should go to the right, and when the user taps the left button ImageView should go to the left of the layout. I have already set my OnClickListener for both the right and left button:

```
package com.example.game;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class PlayActivity extends Activity {
ImageButton leftButton, rightButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
    leftButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    rightButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```

However I do not know what code to put inside the OnClickListener method to make the ImageView move either left or right. Does anyone know the code for animating to the left and to the right?

Comment: What api level do you plan on supporting? This will help determine what options you have when it comes to animation

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.example.game;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;


    public class PlayActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener {
    ImageButton leftButton, rightButton;
    ImageView imgLogo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
        imgLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLogo);


              // load the animation
        animMove = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.move);

        // set animation listener
        animMove.setAnimationListener(this);


        leftButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    imgLogo.startAnimation(animMove);

            }
        });
        rightButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
@Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // Take any action after completing the animation

        // check for zoom in animation
        if (animation == animMove) {
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    }
```

add this xml in anim folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

   <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="75%p"
        android:duration="800" />
</set>
```

Comment: in java it gives me the error "move cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: when you say "anim folder", do you mean the xml of the activity?

Comment: create a folder anim in res folder then save the above xml as move.xml in that folder